# angularjs call another url when using $http.get

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using angular js and I try to use $http.get to call my server side.

my url is "http://www.muslimsquare.com/sandbox/user_login.php" so I put $http.get like

```
$http.get('http://www.muslimsquare.com/sandbox/user_login.php').then(function(resp) {
        alert(resp.status)
      }, function(err) {
        console.error('ERR', err);
});
```

When this code has beed called, I got the error show like this.

[image]

It's look like they call another url, not http://www.muslimsquare.com/sandbox/user_login.php (I user google chrome).  I already try to change url to another domain, its work. just this domain does not work.

does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Regards.

Comment: When you open the link you provided in browser, it is redirected to the URL that appears in your Chrome dev console. Hovewer if you open the link without the `http://` part it returns `{"status":"ok"}`, which is what you expect, right? It may be some server configuration issue rather than problem with your angular code.

Comment: OK, I got it, it about my .htaccess file on my server.